# Why would anybody choose Flink over Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink

I see Spark to be superior to Flink. Below is my research.

1. I see that most of features of Spark are covered in Flink, except for the "fair scheduling" of Spark. I tried googling and going through Flink documentation but had no luck.
2. Also if you see Github, Apache Spark has almost double the popularity (number of stars, forks) when compared to Flink. So I am curious to know why Flink doesn't have as much popularity as Spark.
3. I also see the number of connectors written to Flink are too less/ less maintained than the number of connectors to Spark. (eg: mongodb). Does it mean Flink is yet to be matured or get market traction?

The answers to the above will help us decide on the appropriate technology.

### Edit-1

I am giving more input after having read some answers here.

1. This will mostly be used for batch processing. Realtime streaming may be 10% of the use case.
2. What's more important for me is: when we run into issues we need community support. We can't keep scratching our heads for weeks if not months unable to handle issues --this is where the GitHub stars influence my decision a lot. [priority 1]
3. The deployment will be in the cloud, so cost is super important. Mostly we want to have the cluster with 25% nodes as spot instances (because of cost) [priority 2]. If business incurs more cost but its running, then we are OK. But I don't want to fall into cost optimization trap and finally dent business.
4. Fair scheduling is super important. I can't starve a customer just because the cluster resources are being starved by another customer and will not release the cluster for several hours.
5. One more point of concern I have is: most of the new / emerging technologies first support Spark. (eg: delta lake); So I am thinking: even if I pickup Flink and Flink is really performant -- what's the point, will I end up writing connectors for all rather concentrate on writing business logic.

Note that underlying database is Mongo -- which can't be fully eaten away by the current processing. A head room should be left for real time micro services to act --meaning the Spark/Flink cluster will be limited in size.

### Edit-2

So the question is why would anybody pick up Apache Flink over Spark? Clearly I am missing to see the important value-add of Flink.

Comment: Are you seeking more answers over and above the good answers you have already received? If you need more information, can you ask focussed and specific questions to your existing respondents?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm a Flink committer and I work on Flink at Ververica. It's been quite some time since I worked directly with Spark.

I recommend watching this talk from the Flink Forward conference, where Regina Chen from Goldman Sachs describes how they got significantly better performance and reduced costs by switching to Flink: [Dynamically Generated Flink Jobs at Scale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vJ1VqM4Kl0).

As for `fair scheduling`, Flink doesn't have anything exactly like that. Most of the Flink's community's related efforts over the past few releases have focused on better support for containerized, per-application deployments and [elastic scaling](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/elastic_scaling/), rather than session clusters. The [adaptive batch scheduler](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/elastic_scaling/#adaptive-batch-scheduler) coming in Flink 1.15 might be of interest, for example.

Comment: Hey. i went through the video. Couple of points: Flink can handle max of 25 columns and they have to be notnull. She was telling they wrote a custom serializer to handle this. --Do we already have some ready-made serializers? is this solved problem already?

Comment: One more question is: Can we keep a flink cluster up and running 24X7 and cater to user SQL query on S3 on the fly and return back values (like presto)

Comment: In that video she's speaking about the limitations of Flink's tuple types. There are a number of built-in serializers that don't have this limitation: CSV, JSON, Avro, etc.

Comment: Yes, you can keep a session cluster running 24x7 and use it to handle ad-hoc queries submitted from Flink's sql-client. There are also commercial offerings from Ververica, Decodable, Aiven, etc.

Comment: Ok. i will explore this

Answer (score 0):

As always, choosing for a technology depends on the best fit for the business problem that you're trying to solve. I can't answer that based on the original question. Are you interested in batch or streaming data? Is latency important?  Do you want to perform stateful processing or stateless? How about exactly once state consistency? What are the sources and what are the sinks that you need to connect to? Do you want to write your logic in Java, Scala, SQL, Python or something else? These are just some of the questions you need to consider.